# android in-app purchases API 3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to figure out how to implement in-app purchasing in my app that comprises a dozen of activities. The main question is where to put `IABHelper m_helper;` object? Everything is simple in case on single-activity app (like the sample "android-sdk\extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive\src\com\example\android\trivialdrivesample").

But I need to interact with billing system from within several `Activities`. Is it cool to define a `IABHelper m_helper;` in each of them? I suspect no. If I define it only in my root activity, how do I access it from secondary activities? Moreover, look at a scenario like this:

1. Start app.
2. Root activity launches and billing system (`IABHelper m_helper`) setups.
3. Go to secondary activity. Now I can access (somehow) root activity's `m_helper` because root activity is not destroyed yet.
4. Press home button
5. Launch a million of cool Android apps.
6. Return back to my app. Secondary activity wakes up, but Root is killed by Android on step 5. I lost access to `m_helper`.

Am missing some Android concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IABHelper` provides convenience methods for connecting an `Activity` to the billing `Service`. It is not a global connection, so you can certainly create one for each `Activity` that needs to read/write billing information.

However, make sure you only call `m_helper.setup(this)` once for each Activity (generally in the `onCreate` for that `Activity`). Similarly, only call `m_helper.dispose()` once per `Activity` (usually in the `onDestroy` method).